# Boot entries removed through easybcd. How do I restore Windows 8 MBR?

Tags: windows-8, boot, mbr, ubuntu-12.10

Somebody deleted my easybcd boot entries when I wasn't looking! I had a dual boot with ubuntu. I used my live usb and installed boot repair on the demo. After I used it, my ubuntu install was working, but my windows 8 install isn't working. I clicked restore mbr and windows boot files. Earlier, I used to boot windows 8 by selecting UEFI OS from the boot options. Now whenever I select that it takes me to the ubuntu grub menu. Before I fixed ubuntu it used to show can't find mbr. How do I fix my windows 8 installation without deleting my files? I would prefer a way without the install dvd, from ubuntu itself.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Repair should fix the issue.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

For vieving/editing complete Windows BCD - [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net)

Comment: No, I said I already tried it. It doesn't restore the windows mbr, only the ubuntu mbr.